# Printing a table with sage math

Tags: function, math, html-table, sage

The assignment is to construct a two-column table that starts at x= -4 and ends with x= 5 with one unit increments between consecutive x values. It should have column headings ‘x’ and ‘f(x)’. I can't find anything helpful on `html.table()`, which is what we're supposed to use.

This what I have so far. I just have no idea what to put into the html.table function.

```
x = var('x')
f(x) = (5 * x^2) - (9 * x) + 4
html.table()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [sage's reference documentation page on html.table](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/misc/sage/misc/html.html#sage.misc.html.HTML.table)

It contains the following valuable information :

> table(x, header=False)
>
> Print a nested list as a HTML table. Strings of html will be parsed for math inside dollar and double-dollar signs. 2D graphics will be displayed in the cells. Expressions will be latexed.
>
> INPUT:
>
> ```
>   x – a list of lists (i.e., a list of table rows)
>   header – a row of headers. If True, then the first row of the table is taken to be the header.
> ```

There is also an example for `sin` (instead of `f`) with `x` in `0..3` instead of `-4..5`, that you can probably adapt pretty easily :

```
html.table([(x,sin(x)) for x in [0..3]], header = ["$x$", "$\sin(x)$"])
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it done. I had actually found that documentation page, but I didn't think that that was what I needed because of all the html. Are those bits just supposed to be the html equivalent of the sage syntax?

Answer (score 1):

@Cimbali has a great answer.  For completeness, I'll point out that you should be able to get this information with

```
html.table?
```

or, in fact,

```
table?
```

since I would say we want to advocate the more general [table](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/misc/sage/misc/table.html?highlight=table#sage.misc.table.table) function, which has a lot of good potential for you.